# How to use wordpress widget short code in to php file

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, shortcode

[yottie channel="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCD3H1OkbYIDXjbRD3y3XPrA"]

how to use this short code in to php file.

Comment: Using `do_shortcode()` check this links   https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: also check this https://codex.wordpress.org/it:Riferimento_funzioni/do_shortcode

Answer (score 2):

Just like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[yottie channel="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCD3H1OkbYIDXjbRD3y3XPrA"]' ); ?>
```

Comment: <php? do_shortcode( '[yottie channel="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCD3H1OkbYIDXjbRD3y3XPrA"]' );?>